# How to understand 'A is as simple as B is complicated'?

Tags: sentence-structure, as, compounds

I see one sentence in my book:

> It is easy to see that A is as simple as B is complicated.

I know the subject of the sentence is "*it*" that is "*A is as simple as B is complicated*", but how should I understand "*A is as simple as B is complicated*"? If "*A is as simple as B*", I know that is to say A is simple as B is. Why can the "*is complicated*" can be added to the end? What is the subject and object of the "*A is as simple as B is complicated*"? Does he/she want to say A and B are simple or complicated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we say that A is as *adjective1* as B is *adjective2*, then we are saying that the degree (great or small) to which A is *adjective1* is the same degree to which B is *adjective2*.

A is as simple as B is complicated (B is very complicated, A is very simple).

> Ice is as cold as fire is hot (ice is very cold and fire is very hot).
>
> Tom is as short as Mary is tall (Mary is tall, Tom is short).

The qualities that are of similar degree do not have to be 'opposite' in some way:

> Mary is as musical as her brother is literary.
>
> A well known way of saying someone is honest is to say that they are
> 'as honest as the day is long' (because a day is long).

We can even talk about comparable degrees of qualities in the same person or thing:

> Michael is as handsome as he is clever.
>
> My wife is as talented as she is beautiful.

Comment: Your final example is potentially important, because although we often *do* use this construction in the highly specific form *X is as [ADJ] as Y is [OPPOSITE of ADJ]*, we also use it a lot in contexts where the two adjectives have no direct relationship (there's no connection between ***honest*** and ***long*** apart from in the *specific* context where the *"**great honesty**"* of one referent is likened to the *"**great length**"* of the other referent).